# How inefficient are virtual table JOINs?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a query like this, where I join a number of virtual tables:

```
SELECT table1.a, tbl2.a, tbl3.b, tbl4.c, tbl5.a, tbl6.a
FROM table1
JOIN (SELECT x, a, b, c FROM table2 WHERE foo='bar') tbl2 ON table1.x = tbl2.x
JOIN (SELECT x, a, b, c FROM table3 WHERE foo='bar') tbl3 ON table1.x = tbl3.x
JOIN (SELECT x, a, b, c FROM table4 WHERE foo='bar') tbl4 ON table1.x = tbl2.x
JOIN (SELECT x, a, b, c FROM table5 WHERE foo='bar') tbl5 ON table1.x = tbl5.x
JOIN (SELECT x, a, b, c FROM table6 WHERE foo='bar') tbl6 ON table1.x = tbl6.x
WHERE anotherconstraint='value'
```

In my real query, each JOIN has its own JOINs, aggregate functions, and WHERE constraints.

**How well/poorly would a query like this run?** Also, what is the impact difference between this and running all of the individual virtual tables as their own query and linking the results together outside of SQL?

Comment: You mean, opposed to real table JOINs? Profile it! It will depend on many factors and a lot of them will be dependent on your data/schema. Also, linking the results outside SQL will very likely be a lot slower. If you are seeing huge performance problems you might need an index over x or foo in all tables

Comment: In my real query, each of the JOINs has many other WHERE clause constraints, additional joins, and aggregate functions, which is why I split them off as virtual tables. Perhaps there is a better way to go about it?

Comment: If each subquery is complex, then you really should profile it. See the execution plan and learn how to read them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing inherently bad about using inline views (which is AFAIK the correct term for what you call "virtual tables").  I do recommend learning to view and understand execution plans so you can investigate specific performance issues.

In general, I think it's a very bad idea to execute multiple single-table queries and then essentially join the results together in your front-end code.  Doing joins is what an RDBMS is designed for, why re-write it?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
SELECT table1.a, tbl2.a, tbl3.b, tbl4.c, tbl5.a, tbl6.a
FROM table1 JOIN table2 on table1.x = table2.x AND table2.foo = 'bar'
            JOIN table3 on table1.x = table3.x AND table3.foo = 'bar'
            JOIN table4 on table1.x = table4.x AND table4.foo = 'bar'
            JOIN table5 on table1.x = table5.x AND table5.foo = 'bar'
            JOIN table6 on table1.x = table6.x AND table6.foo = 'bar'
WHERE anotherconstraint='value';
```

EDIT:

How well would it run? Who knows? As @Vinko states, the answer lies in looking at the execution plan, perhaps supplying hints where appropriate. Something this complex cannot be answered by looking at a contrived example.

Comment: See my edit above -- each virtual table JOIN has its own JOINs, aggregate functions, and WHERE constraints.